# How to read data from single page app by ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there effective way to read data from single page app build by react or angular by ruby? Using HTTParty or something like that only get home page.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You'll need a user agent capable of running JS. I haven't tried, but opening the app with a selenium/firefox combo should work.

Comment: I need an embedded one, because I want to use it in a rails app. Im trying bower gem, hope it work

Comment: Usually, a single page application communicates with a server via an API. I would now to build something that runs against the HTML of the single page app Instead, I would try to connect directly to the underlying API.

Answer (score 0):

With `HTTParty` you can only make HTTP requests, typically a SPA will communicate with the server via an API. But sometimes to data is in the HTML of the page so a combination of HTTParty and Nokogiri would make scrapping the data doable.

The easiest way to scrap data from a SPA is to use an headless browser like `selenium` with `chrome-driver` (configured as headless).